# Bind handlebars to application object in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Q: How do I bind handlebars to an application object variable, such that when that variable updates, the handlebar data on the screen updates also?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kQuVG/3/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{App.Player.stats.basic}} Scrap
</script>
<button>Add Scrap</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.Player = Em.Object.create({
    stats:{
        basic: 10,
        premium: 20
    }
});    

$('button').click(function(){
    console.log(App.Player.stats.basic);
    App.Player.stats.basic += 10;
    console.log(App.Player.stats.basic);
});
```

The fiddle isn't even working, what I'd like to do is to click the button and add 10 onto the App.Player.stats.scrap value, and have that reflected in the output pane. Is this even the right way to be doing this?

Thanks in advance.

G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with the fiddle. You should always be using Ember's universal accessors when setting and getting properties on any object (even singletons and "App/Namespace global" properties). Ember also has specific naming conventions, like not using capital letters to start instances of objects ('people', not 'People'). And you should also probably use the target/action interface.

I've created a fiddle with these changes. http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Ac2hs/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{App.playerObj.stats.basic}} Scrap <br />
  <button {{action "click" target="App.playerController"}}>Add Scrap</button>
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
var get = Ember.get, getPath = Ember.getPath, set = Ember.set, setPath = Ember.setPath;

App = Ember.Application.create();

set(App, 'playerObj', Object.create({
    stats:Ember.Object.create({
        basic: 10,
        premium: 20
    })
}));

set(App, 'playerController', Ember.Object.create({
    click: function(view) {
        getPath(App, 'playerObj.stats').incrementProperty('basic', 10);
    }
}));
```

​

Comment: Just an note: `Ember.Button` is deprecated so you should use the `{{action}}` helper: `<input {{action "click" target="App.playerController"}}>Add Scrap</button>`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Twg6V/

Comment: This is why I love the Ember community. I've update my answer. Thanks @pangratz. I was unaware of the depreciation.

Comment: There is even a simpler solution: `getPath(App, 'playerObj.stats').incrementProperty('basic', 10);`

Comment: Well hello long forgotten friend `incrementProperty`... :)

Comment: Can I just say a massive "thanks" to everyone, I've been looking for an MVC style javascript lib, and after the response I got from the community I'll definitely be sticking with ember.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a setter and not assign values directly. I've updated the fiddle with something that works.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQuVG/4/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{App.Player.stats.basic}} Scrap
</script>
<button>Add Scrap</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.Player = Em.Object.create({
    stats:{
        basic: 10,
        premium: 20
    }
});    

$('button').click(function(){
    console.log(App.Player.stats.basic);
    App.Player.setPath('stats.basic',  App.Player.getPath('stats.basic') + 10);
    console.log(App.Player.stats.basic);
});
```